# How do I display stereo tracks as mono in Audacity?

Tags: audacity

I am editing a project in Audacity where everything is recorded with Stereo audio. This has the unfortunate side effect of making every track take up double the vertical space. If I convert each track to mono it takes up less space, but I want my final mix to still be in stereo.

Is there a way to display a single waveform per audio track in Audacity without converting my project to mono?

[image]